# Routing and URL handling Angular

Tags: angular, routes, angular6

as it always is, after registration backend send me a url to confirm account. I got full url:
https://app.com/confirm/{userName}/{token}

Username and token are data that I need to handle and send in back request. The thing is I don't know how to handle it. When I make routing:

```
/confirm/:userName/:token
```

It's wrong because token got unknown number of / (slashes) so routing think that this is the path for it.
How can I resolve that problem?
I tried with RouterActivated and RouterActivatedSnapshot. I got ** with redirect to error page so when I do it as above, it always go to error page. Any suggestions?

Comment: You should URL encode the token before adding it to the URL

Comment: On the backend they need to encode and than I catch it as param and decode? Is there any other way? I got from backend url as above and I need to do it untill tomorrow so any other solutions I will appreciate.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion you should:

1. Encode url before adding it to email
2. Pass token as query param - because token may be very long

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use custom [`UrlMatcher`](https://angular.io/api/router/UrlMatcher):

```
...
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    matcher: tokenMatcher,
    component: TestComponent
  }
];
...

/**
 * custom url matcher for router config
 */
export function tokenMatcher(url: UrlSegment[]) {

  if (url.length > 2 && url[0].path === 'confirm') {
    return {
      consumed: url,
      posParams: {
        userName: url[1],
        token: new UrlSegment(url.slice(2).map(u => u.path).join('/'), {})
      }
    }
  }

  return null;
}
```

[STACKBLITZ](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-giqwh5?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts)